# How to create a record in ember.js while throwing a required data to it's relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Please help me. I have a two model which are `foo` and `bar` models. I was trying to create a record on `/foos` endpoint using the `POST` `/foos`. However
  the post `POST` `/foos` has a requirement of `relationships.bar.data.id=1,2,3`. Please see my code below for `/components/foo-bar.js`. My question is how to create a foo record and declaring those ids to it's relationship?

```
/components/foo-bar.js

  foo.setProperties({
    bar: [1213,1231]
  });


 /models/foo.js
 import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.Model.extend({
    bar:  DS.belongsTo('bar', { async: true }),
  });

  /models/bar.js
  import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.Model.extend({
    foos:  DS.hasMany('foo', { async: true }),
  });
```

Comment: Did you read the guides about relationships? Especially the part about [creating records with relationships](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_creating-records)?

Comment: Hi, yes I did. Sadly, upon creating the foo the relationship value is still null. I looked upon the request body on my network's tab

Answer (score 1):

Your `Foo` model uses `belongsTo` which indicates that it can be related to a single `bar`. You would save that bar like

```
/components/foo-bar.js
  let bar = this.store.createRecord('bar', {
    id: 1213
  });
  foo.setProperties({
    bar: bar
  });
```

If you expect to be able to set one `foo` to be related to many `bar` models then you would use `hasMany` and set it like:

```
/components/foo-bar.js
  let bar1 = this.store.createRecord('bar', {
    id: 1213
  });
  let bar2 = this.store.createRecord('bar', {
    id: 3456
  });
  foo.setProperties({
    bars: [bar1, bar2]
  });
```

In either case you should set the actual model `bar` onto `foo` and not just the ID.